# $\lim_{n \to \infty} f^{(n)}(n) \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is not periodic

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ (and $f$ is not a constant function) , such that :
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f^{(n)}(n) \in \mathbb{R}$$

Then $f$ is not periodic ?

What I've managed to proove is that : 
$f$ is periodic $\Rightarrow$ $f'$ is periodic.

So maybe using the fact that the sequence : $u_n = f^{(n)}(n)$ is not periodic is a good idea.

Thank you.

Comment: $f$ is not constant...

Comment: What about $f(n)=\sin(kn)$ for some $k<1$? it is periodic and $|f^{(n)}(n)|<k^n\to0$

Comment: Why not? $\cos(\pi/4)\approx 1.42/2=2.84/4<3.14/4\approx\pi/4$

Comment: Do you intend that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or do you intend that we take [fractional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the two ideas in comments with a small tweak...

Let $f(x) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$, then, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$u_n = f^{(n)}(n) = 0$, which clearly has a real limit.